# For Loop Overwriting Data within Array

Tags: vba

So I have a data set that is made up of a variety tag numbers - I'm trying to develop a VBA "fucntion" to basically give recommendation on a tag number when inputting a new one. This would be easy but the current list gives gaps within tag numbers (eg) goes 4001 4002 4005 . This bit of code is taking that gap and storing "option" tags which I plan to display to the user (so 4003 and 4004). The problem is that these gaps are encountered more than once eg) 4001 4002 4005 4006 4007 4011 4012 and when it comes to the second gap (4008 4009 4010) it overwrites the existing array - how can I get it take each gap and then begin the array below that?

My code is as follows:

```
For j = 2 To UBound(strArrayNumber)

 If strArrayNumber(j) <> strArrayNumber(j - 1) + 1 Then

Gap = strArrayNumber(j) - strArrayNumber(j - 1) 

For b = 1 To Gap 

ReDim TagOptions(1 To Gap) As Integer

TagOptions(b) = strArrayNumber(j - 1) + b
sh.Cells(b, 6) = TagOptions(b)

Next b

End If
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I also often forgot about the [Preserve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement) keyword. Just add it `ReDim Preserve TagOptions(1 To Gap) As Integer` and move up it before `For b =...`  However, I re-read your code again - I am afraid that my advice will not help

Comment: Don't use an array, use a dictionary, then what you are trying to do will be much easier.

Comment: @freeflow Can you show the implementation? I will gladly vote

Comment: @JohnSUN.  Bare bone answer provided.  The OP code is probably best represented by the NextFreeGap function where the exists method nicely demonstrates the advantage of a dictionary over an array.

Comment: Hi - sorry about the deal in replying but this is all very useful. Dictionary was exactly what I was looking for and your other solutions will simply help me solve the problem faster!  I am very new to VBA and getting used to it all so thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's not calculate the Gap. The parameters of the cycle by B can be any - we will use this. Try this:

```
Set oCell = sh.Range("F1")
TagOptions = Array()
For j = 2 To UBound(strArrayNumber)
    If strArrayNumber(j) <> strArrayNumber(j - 1) + 1 Then
        For b = strArrayNumber(j - 1) + 1 To strArrayNumber(j) - 1
            uBoundTagOptions = UBound(TagOptions) + 1
            ReDim Preserve TagOptions(1 To uBoundTagOptions)
            TagOptions(uBoundTagOptions) = b
            oCell.Value = b
            Set oCell = oCell.Offset(1, 0)
        Next b
    End If
Next j
```

Don't forget to specify `Option Base 1` at the beginning of the module, otherwise `TagOptions = Array()` will create an empty array [0..-1] , with `LBound = 0`, but you want from `LBound = 1`

**UPDATE**

By the way, there is one old trick using an auxiliary array. This is used to clear data from duplicates, for sorting and other things. The method is resource-intensive, but very fast. It looks something like this:

```
Function getGaps(aData As Variant) As Variant
Dim lB As Long, uB As Long, i As Long, lCount As Long
Dim aTemp() As Boolean, aResult() As Long
    If IsArray(aData) Then
        lB = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(aData)
        uB = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(aData)
Rem Let's create an auxiliary array of boolean flags. It may be very large, but it won't be long.
        ReDim aTemp(lB To uB)
Rem Let's mark in the array those values ??that are in the aData.
Rem In this case, we will skip duplicates, if any, and count the number of unique numbers.
        lCount = 0
        For i = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
            If Not aTemp(aData(i)) Then
                aTemp(aData(i)) = True
                lCount = lCount + 1
            End If
        Next i
Rem Number of values in gaps:
        uB = uB - lB - lCount + 1
        If uB > 0 Then ' It may be that there were no gaps in the array
            ReDim aResult(1 To uB)
            lCount = 0
            For i = LBound(aTemp) To UBound(aTemp)
                If Not aTemp(i) Then
                    lCount = lCount + 1
                    aResult(lCount) = i
                End If
            Next i
Rem Here it is - the result of the function
            getGaps = aResult
Rem The interpreter will destroy this variable immediately after exiting the function,
Rem but will free the memory a little later. This line should help free memory faster
            ReDim aTemp(0)
        End If
    End If
Rem In all other cases, the function will return Empty
End Function
```

Despite the number of lines, it is very simple and very fast since all the work is done in RAM.

With this function, all the code you showed in your question becomes:

```
Set oCell = sh.Range("F1")
oCell.EntireColumn.ClearContents ' This is for the case where no gaps are found
TagOptions = getGaps(strArrayNumber)
If IsEmpty(TagOptions) Then
    Debug.Print "No gaps in array"
    Exit Sub
End If
oCell.Resize(UBound(TagOptions), 1).Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TagOptions)
```

Of course TRANSPOSE () might not work correctly for a very large array. But I hope that you are not so cruel to your users and the list of possible tags does not exceed a hundred or two.

Answer (score 1):

At the prompting of @JohnSUN here is the bare bones of a solution using Scripting.Dictionary.

The OP desires to manage a data set.  To simplify this management I have chosen to create a TagList object.  The TagList object allows

1. Population of the tag list from two arrays
2. Updating the value associated with a tag item
3. getting back an array of tags or object
4. getting an array of the next free tags
5. testing if a tag exists

This is a bare bones example as it is designed to point the way rather than provide a complete solution.  It has some obvious ommisions, i.e. there is no code for what happens if a the request for the next set of free tags uses a tag that is higher then the maximum tag number, there is no error code for what happens if we try to add an existing tag to the TagList etc.

The Class Taglist code compiles without error and shows no significant inospection results after a Rubberduck code inspection

**Class TagList**

```
Option Explicit

Private Type State
    ' Requires a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
    TagList As Scripting.Dictionary
    
End Type

Private s As State


Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set s.TagList = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(ByVal iptag As Long) As Variant
    Item = s.TagList.Item(iptag)
End Property

Public Property Let Item(ByVal iptag As Long, ByVal ipitem As Variant)
    s.TagList.Item(iptag) = ipitem
End Property

Public Function Tags() As Variant

    Tags = s.TagList.keys
    
End Function

Public Function Items() As Variant

    Items = s.TagList.Items
    
End Function


Public Sub Add(ByVal ipTags As Variant, Optional ByVal ipItems As Variant)
'ipTags and ipItems should be arrays of equal size

    If IsMissing(ipItems) Then
    
        ReDim ipItems(UBound(ipTags) - LBound(Tags) + 1)
        
    End If
    
    If (UBound(ipTags) - LBound(ipTags)) - (UBound(ipItems) - LBound(ipItems)) <> 0 Then
    
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 512, "Size Error", "Arrays are different sizes"
        
    End If
    
    Dim myItemsIndex As Long
    myItemsIndex = LBound(ipItems)
    
    Dim myTag As Variant
    For Each myTag In ipTags
    
        s.TagList.Add myTag, CVar(ipItems(myItemsIndex))
        myItemsIndex = myItemsIndex + 1
        
    Next
    
End Sub


Public Function Exists(ByVal iptag As Long) As Boolean
    
    Exists = s.TagList.Exists(iptag)
    
End Function


Public Function NextFreeTags(ByVal iptag As Long) As Variant

    If iptag < 1 Then
    
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 512, "Negative Tag", "Tag numbers must be positive"
    
    End If
    
    Dim myFreeTags As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myFreeTags = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Do While s.TagList.Exists(iptag)
        
        iptag = iptag + 1
    
    Loop
    
    Do Until s.TagList.Exists(iptag)
    
        myFreeTags.Add iptag, iptag
        iptag = iptag + 1
        
    Loop
    
    NextFreeTags = myFreeTags.keys
    
End Function
```

Thus we can now do the following

```
Dim myTagList as TagList
Set myTagList = New TagList
mytaglist.Add Array(4006, 4001, 4002, 4011, 4005,  4007)
' Note the above is the short form version we could equally say
' myTagList.add Array(4006, 4001, 4002, 4011, 4005,  4007), Array(Obj6, Obj1, Obj11, Obj5, Obj7)

'Oops, we forgot to add tag 4012
myTaglist.add array(4012)

' getting then next free tags
dim myTags as variant
myTags = myTaglist.NextFreeTags(4001)
```

etc

Comment: Yes, there is a little more code than the OP. But if the application is intensively working with sequential numbers - for example, blanks of insurance policies - such a class (after revision) can greatly facilitate writing the main code. Thank you, it was educational.

Comment: Maybe some explanations would be helpful to cover OP. - Further hints: a) typo in calling example: of course the correct syntax is `Set myTagList = New TagListClass` (instead of `.. As New ..`). - b) **tl;dr** and didn't test, but redimming in the `IsMissing` check within the  `Add` routine (comparing identity of array/dictionary boundaries) might possibly be changed to `ReDim ipItems(UBound(ipTags) - LBound(Tags) + 0)` (instead of `+1`) otherwise the subsequent escape condition raises an intentional error. c) undeclared variable name should be either `myTag` or `myTags` @freeflow

Comment: @T.M. a) Corrected the as new.  b) Array 1 to 10 is 10 items but 10-1 is 9 so the +1 is needed.  A common off by 1 error. c) corrected to myTags  Thanks for the feedback.